# "Select Top 10, then Join Tables", instead of "Select Top 10 from Joined Tables"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have inherited a stored procedure which performs joins across eight tables, some of which contain hundreds of thousands of rows, then selects the top ten entries from the result of that join.

I have enough information at the start of the procedure to select those ten rows from a single table, and then perform those joins on those ten rows, rather than on hundreds of thousands of intermediate rows.

How do I select those top ten rows and then only do joins on those ten rows, instead of performing joins all of the thousands of rows in the table?

Comment: Normalyl the uery optimizer does that. Check execution plans - you may simply have a total non issue here.

Comment: The query returns the last ten records users have worked on. The issue came to light because the users who have worked on the largest number of records are seeing the worst of the problems. I'll concede that I might be looking at issue incorrectly, but it's definitely not a non-issue

Comment: Yeah, like for example... are all indies there?

Comment: Just to confirm, the problem was definitely that the ten most recent entries was being selected late, selecting the top 10 *after* joining on thousands of rows. The top 10 are now selected in a subquery early on (solved by Marco) and then many fewer joins are performed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I should try:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM your_table
     ORDER BY your_condition) p
INNER JOIN second_table t
    ON p.field = t.field
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The optimizer may not be able to perform the top 10 first if you have inner joins, since it can't be sure that the inner joins won't exclude rows later on. It would be a bug if it selected 10 rows from the main table, and then only returned 7 rows at the end because of a join. Using Marco's rewrite may gain you performance for this reason since you're expressly stating that it's safe to limit the rows before the joins.
2. If you're query is sufficiently complicated, the query plan optimizer may run out of time finding a good plan. It's only given a few hundred milliseconds, and with even a few joins there are probably thousands of different ways it can execute the query (different join orders, etc). If this is the case, you'll benefit from storing the first 10 rows in a temp table first, and then using that later like this:

   ```
   select top 10 *
   into #MainResults
   from MyTable
   order by your_condition;


   select *
   from #MainResults r
   join othertable t
     on t.whatever = r.whatever;
   ```

   I've seen cases where this second approach has made a HUGE difference.

Comment: Hmm I almost always had the opposite experience. Moving temp tables into inline views, CTE's, or plain old joins does better than temp tables

Comment: It totally depends on the scale. If the number of rows is small (in this case, 10) it's probably worth it. If they start getting higher, than it'll def not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CTE to define the top X and then use it

For example this [data.se query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/237/journey-to-be-a-generalist) limits only to top 40 tags

```
with top40 as (
  select top 40 t.id, t.tagname
  from tags t, posttags pt
  where pt.tagid = t.id
  group by t.tagname, t.id
  order by count(pt.postid) desc
),

myanswers as(
  select p.parentid, p.score
  from posts p
  where
    p.owneruserid = ##UserID## and
    p.communityowneddate is null
)

select t40.tagname as 'Tag', sum(p1.score) as 'Score',
case when sum(p1.score) >= 15 then ':-)' else ':-(' end as 'Status'
from top40 t40, myanswers p1, posttags pt1
where
  pt1.postid = p1.parentid and
  pt1.tagid = t40.id
group by t40.tagname
order by sum(p1.score) desc
```

Comment: This is equivalent to marco's answer; a CTE is just a more elegant syntax for a nested subquery. (There are some exceptions, but in this case it's true).